# Mix a Forward Delta Premium Adjusted and a Forward Delta to construct the volatility surface

Tags: options, volatility

I have two brokers who give me delta strategies for USD-COP, but one of them gives me the issue with forward delta, the another one is premium adjusted. Besides, how can I mix them for construct a volatility surface in deltas and strikes?

Comment: Are these for the same maturity ? If yes why not build two separate smiles and see if they are close to each other ?

Comment: Yes, same maturity. but i need to publish just one smile that combine both inputs